# Execution / Timing difference depending upon statement styles

Tags: c, iar

How would the below two statements differ wrt timing / execution. 
I am working on AT91CSAM7x512 device. 
We were able to resolve a troublesome bug by changing the below assignment style.

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench Ver 4.41A. Is this happening due to some compiler directive or some other reason ?

---

```
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_PER  |= (((unsigned int)1<<12) | ((unsigned int)1<<13));  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_ODR  |= (((unsigned int)1<<12) | ((unsigned int)1<<13));  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_IFER |= (((unsigned int)1<<12) | ((unsigned int)1<<13));  
MARK1.occurrence = 0;  
MARK2.occurrence = 0;
```

---

```
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_PER  |= (unsigned int)1<<12) ;  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_ODR  |= (unsigned int)1<<12) ;  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_IFER |= (unsigned int)1<<12) ;  
MARK1.occurrence = 0;


AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_PER  |= (unsigned int)1<<13) ;  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_ODR  |= (unsigned int)1<<13) ;  
AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_IFER |= (unsigned int)1<<13) ;  
MARK2.occurrence = 0;
```

Would this have anything to do with the way the stack is handeled @ instructions 
i am comparatively new to processors & need help with this.

Comment: Could it be some timing-issue? Is any assignment to a hardware register?

Comment: @ timing issue ...I think yes. I think it is something to do with the stack push & pop that occurs every time the processor / compiler comes across this statement. The collective statement (1st set of commands) works fine, the probable reason i can think of is that it is faster & requires lesser commands.

Comment: The first version reads and writes the PIOA registers once, and sets 2 bits simultaneously.  The second version reads and writes the PIOA registers twice, and sets first one bit then the other.  Not having any idea what those bits denote, nor whether reading those registers changes things at all, I can't help much further, but at the device level, it could be quite significantly different.

Comment: If those are hardware registers, you'll presumably have to define the fields as `volatile`, else the compiler can even do your second set of instructions just like the first ones (the `->PIO_...` aren't used in between, instead of updating twice compute what the effect of both is and do it in one go).